# When does multiplication by an orthogonal matrix preserves the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix, with rank $\ge n-1$.

> Suppose that the eigenvalues (counted with multiplicities) of $A$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $QA$ for some **orthogonal** matrix $Q$. Must $Q$ be diagonal?

The condition $\text{rank}(A)\ge n-1$ is necessary: If we allow $\text{rank}(A)< n-1$, then one can take $A$ to be block diagonal with the $2 \times 2$ zero matrix as its first block. Then the entire $\text{O}(2) \times \text{Id}_{n-2}$ preserves the eigenvalues.

Comment: Am I missing something, or would $A$ being a reflection matrix, and $Q$ a rotation matrix not always work? My intuition on isometries in higher than three dimensions is rusty, so maybe not

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. (at least I am sure it works in $2D$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider
$$
R=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0},\ Q=\pmatrix{R\\ &R},\ A=\pmatrix{R\\ &I},\ QA=\pmatrix{I\\ &R}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, this is a great example. I now wonder whether the fact that $A$ has a diagonal block-structure forces $Q$ to have the same block structure. Maybe you have an idea/guess about that?

Comment: @AsafShachar I haven't any intuition about this, but perhaps $Q$ and $A$ are simultaneously triangulable over $\mathbb C$. They certainly aren't always simultaneously diagonalisable, as shown by the example $$Q=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1\\ &&1\\ &&&-1},\ A=\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\ &1&1&1\\ &&-1&1\\ &&&-1}.$$